# how to fix a space, line break character error when building "dotnet build"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, entity-framework-migrations

Everytime I try to build the project using dotnet build I get an error that says.

A space or line break was encountered after the "@" character. Showing Details.cshtml (796,17) on the error message which I assume is the line number where the error is being thrown. The line that has @Html.Action is throwing 796

here is my code below

```
 @if(User.IsInRole("CFO") || User.IsInRole("Manager") || User.IsInRole("CEO") || User.IsInRole("Finance Manager") || User.IsInRole("IT-Line Manager") || User.IsInRole("IT-HOD")
                            || User.IsInRole("SupplyChainBuyer") || User.IsInRole("SupplyChainManager"))
                            {
                                <a asp-action="ApproveRequisition" asp-route-id="@Model.RequisitionId" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true">Approve</a>
                            }|
                            @if(User.IsInRole("SupplyChainBuyer"))
                            
                             
                                @Html.ActionLink("Automate RFQ", "IndexMethod", "RFQ", new { RequisitionNo = @Model.RequisitionNo }, null);

                            }|
                            @if (User.IsInRole("CFO") || User.IsInRole("Manager") || User.IsInRole("CEO") || User.IsInRole("Finance Manager") || User.IsInRole("IT-Line Manager") || User.IsInRole("IT-HOD"))
                            {
                                <a asp-action="DeclineRequisition" asp-route-id="@Model.RequisitionId" class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true">Decline</a>

                            }|
                            @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                            {
                                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.RequisitionId" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">Edit</a>
                            }
```

Comment: Okay, so which of the lines you've shown is line 796?

Comment: Sometimes Visual Studio has cache problems when you're compiling razor pages and what he show in errors is just a "pre compile check" but that checks not the same version of what he built, so the build is success althought errors listed in the tab, and althought the incoerence between errors there and what you have in the cshtml page. If you don't see any spaces between "@" char and the statement, try to close the tab of Details.cshtml and open it again, build again and then, if it's a cache problem, no error would appear anymore in the list

Comment: You are missing the opening brace `{` after `@if(User.IsInRole("SupplyChainBuyer"))`